# How many bytes does a non-inline non-virtual method add to the instance of a class? C++

Tags: c++, memory, vtable

Take these two classes for example (C++)

```
class B1 {
public:

};

class B2 {
public:
  void f0 () {}
  void f1 () {}
};
```

How much bigger would class `B2` be in memory Vs `B1`

I feel like it's one of two answers:

A single 4 byte `int` pointer on 32 bit systems PER method.

Or something similar to what happens with Virtual Method Tables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Where there would be one 4 byte `int` pointer that points to a table for each class so it can look up it's methods, which would make sense, but I don't know if this happens for non-virtual methods.

Thanks.

Edit : Thanks for all of the awesome and quick replies :)  (Also marked answer)

Comment: A simple trick: Test it in your compiler and see if you can falsify your hypothesis.

Comment: Note that even if you try it and your this does not falsify you're hypothesis, it doesn't mean your hypothesis is valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, where in memory are class functions put?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648647/in-c-where-in-memory-are-class-functions-put) (with credit to [@Sid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559095/sid) for finding it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**None.**

Non-virtual methods don't increase a class's size.

As for `virtual` methods, only the first one added to a class will increase its size, all subsequent ones do not.

The fact that it's `inline` or not also doesn't affect the class size.

The reason for this is that extra memory is not needed. Just imagine if all instances of all classes held pointers to all methods in the class and all parent classes. That would be a huge waste of memory.

```
B2 b;
b.f0();
```

the compiler can simply generate code to call `B2::f0()`. The `this` pointer is passed as an under-the-hood parameter so that the method know on which instance of the class to operate.

For a simple test:

```
class B1 {
public:

};

class B2 {
public:
  void f0 () {}
  void f1 () {}
};

//...
assert( sizeof(B1) == sizeof(B2) );
```

Comment: How would you prove this is true in C++ and why is this the case?

Comment: @mmacdermaid I already explained why this is the case: 1) there's no need for it, as the methods need no dynamic binding (like in the case of virtual methods) 2) huge memory waste. As for proving it, you can compare the size of your 2 classes.

Comment: Add a method and use sizeof to calculate before and after size.

Comment: I caught your reply before you edited.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: @mmacdermaid: I'm not sure the behavior is actually required by the standard, since it's (reportedly) possible to implement a C++ interpreter.  However, in all practical implementations (and therefore, all popular compilers), the method address is hard-coded by the compiler at compile time and never needs to be looked-up/accessed/computed at run-time, so there is no need to store a pointer to look up the address.

Comment: @AndréCaron that's a good point. I didn't bother to look in the standard, but I'm assuming that if someone is bright enough to write a compiler, he would never have non-virtual methods increase object size.

Answer (score 0):

Luchian's answer is correct. I just want to add that code is kept on the `text` segment which is different from where the data resides (`data` segment). Hence, the only time methods affect an object's size is when there is (at least one) a virtual method hence forcing a `vptr` to be placed inside the object (for every instance). Read this to get more enlightened on the segments part: [In C++, where in memory are class functions put?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648647/in-c-where-in-memory-are-class-functions-put)

Comment: Since this is not an answer, I suggest you make this a comment.  Nice link, BTW!

Comment: That's a good reference, which appears to cover this question completely enough to mark this one as a dupe.

Comment: I would add that once there is at least one virtual method, than there will ALSO be one "instance" of a virtual table per object. Its size will be the size of pointer multiply by the number of virtual methods for this object (but in practice it might be compiler dependent).